# Logon with Amazon for Alexa Skills (LWA)

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Has anyone got an end-to-end solution for LWA and AWS Lambda?  About when I think I understand the request/response protocol I get more confused when I try to make it work.

Comment: I am using Logon with Amazon to authenticate my users.  It seems to be working just fine but I need the profile information that is seemingly authorized during client logon.  Problem is I can not see how one accesses the information from the Smart Home linked Lambda function.

Comment: Some code or link of reference has always helped me help others.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is:  https://api.amazon.com/user/profile.  You must pass the OAuth 2.0 token in one of three ways:  As a parameter in the URL, as a 'bearer' token on the header or as XML.  Here is a link:  https://login.amazon.com/website.  The token is very long and per Amazon should be encoded.  That may make it too long for a URL.  I used the header approach.

```
    public static WebClient client = new WebClient();
    public static JObject GetAmznProfile(string token)
    {
        string amznProfileHost = "https://api.amazon.com/user/profile";
        try
        {
            client.Headers.Remove("user-agent");
            client.Headers.Remove("Authorization");
            client.Headers.Add("Authorization: bearer " + token);
        }
        catch { Logger(Constants.SEVERE, "Exception caught trying to modify http headers in \"GetAmznProfile\""); }
        finally { }

        string body = GetUrl(amznProfileHost);
        if (body != null)
        {
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(body);
            return json;
        }
        else
        {
            string error = @"{'user_id':'error','name':'error','email':'error'}";
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(error);
            return json;
        }
    }

    public static string GetUrl(string url)
    {
        Logger(Constants.DEBUG, "In 'GetUrl' the URL is " + url);
        try
        {
            Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            data.Close();
            reader.Close();

            return body;
        }
        catch (WebException e) { Logger(Constants.INFO, e.ToString() + " exception caught"); return null; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my search to find the solution to this question I stumbled upon this question. NHLIVES' answer is not a drop in for me since I'm using node.js. The following code is incomplete and modified from Amazon's example but should be error free. It certainly can be improved upon. But it worked for me and I hope it's useful for the next person down the road.

One more thing, module 'request' isn't available in Lambda so you have to supply it. Just make a zip file having your index.js in the top level, a node_modules directory containing 'request' and 'safe-buffer' directories (copied from your local node installation) and upload the zip file to Amazon Lambda (In AWS Lambda: 'Code entry type': 'Upload a .zip file').

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var requestlib = require('request');

exports.handler = function (request, context) {

    var whoami = async function (request) {
        var amznProfileURL = 'https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token=';

        if (request.directive.header.namespace === 'Alexa.Discovery' && request.directive.header.name === 'Discover') {
            amznProfileURL += request.directive.payload.scope.token;
        } else {
            amznProfileURL += request.directive.endpoint.scope.token;
        }

        await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            log("LWArequest: ", "amznProfileURL ", amznProfileURL);
            requestlib(amznProfileURL, function(error, response, body) {
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var profile = JSON.parse(body);
                    log("LWArequest: ", "user_id ", body);
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    log("LWArequest: ", "error ", "can't connect to Amazon Profile Service");
                    reject();
                }
            });
        }
        );
    }

    whoami(request);
    if (request.directive.header.namespace === 'Alexa.Discovery' && request.directive.header.name === 'Discover') {
        log("DEBUG:", "Discover request",  JSON.stringify(request));
        handleDiscovery(request, context, "");
    }

    function log(message, message1, message2) {
        console.log(message + message1 + message2);
    }

}
```

You should see something like this in your CloudWatch Log file:

```
2018-07-17T23:06:28.108Z    08d795d3-8a16-11e8-b912-0f46b6510aa8    
  LWArequest: amznProfileURL https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token=Atza|IwEBIP5ozi...

2018-07-17T23:06:28.409Z    08d795d3-8a16-11e8-b912-0f46b6510aa8    
  LWArequest: user_id
  {
    "user_id": "amzn1.account.A..........................A"
  }
```

Hope it helps.